# Get childrens files from an ID folder in Google Drive

Tags: java, servlets, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get all the files / folders from a parent folder.

I managed to get the ID of the parent folder. When I try to get the file information, I can, if I Use the ID as indicated on this page live example : https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get

However, when I try to get any file data with the page code sample :

```
  try {
      File file = service.files().get(fileId).execute();

      System.out.println("Title: " + file.getTitle());
      System.out.println("Description: " + file.getDescription());
      System.out.println("MIME type: " + file.getMimeType());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("An error occured: " + e);
    }
  }
```

I get nothing, except get this error message :

com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 OK

```
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "File not found: 0Bz8fRNYAOdjjd05ydVRCROE4QlE",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "File not found: 0Bz8fRNYAOdjjd05ydVRCROE4QlE"
}
```

How could I get any data from the  file / folder with its ID?

Thank you very much in advance and greetings !

Comment: This showed up as linked to a [question I answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26511945/404-error-when-trying-to-get-document-metadata-via-the-google-drive-api/26727594#comment42099407_26727594), so thought I'd direct you there if you're still having the issue 10 months later.

Answer (score 1):

404 means either (1) the ID is wrong, or (2) you don't have permission to access that folder.

To confirm the ID, use Try It at https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#try-it and see if the file can be retrieved.

If this works, check that the user and scope that your app is using allow access.

Comment: Hi!

I  tried with this example, and I get the information of the file. 

However, When I use the Java Code I can't get the file info.

This is the code that I used:

` String query="'"+FileId+"' in parents";
     Files.List request = service.files().list().setQ(query);
       try {
         FileList files = request.execute();
         result.addAll(files.getItems());
         request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
       } catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
         request.setPageToken(null);
       }
     

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check what I suggested?

Also you should enable http tracing and compare the http your app is sending vs. the http from Try It