# 404 Error when trying to get document metadata via the google drive API

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am authenticating using [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation).

I am getting back the google drive service that looks like this: `com.google.api.services.drive.Drive@6ebd27b9`

This is the link to the file I'm trying to retrieve: `https://docs.google.com/a/rmi.org/document/d/1JRS8SLzaAD2U4cG-GbDMbVN25Dp6f_uUYyl6ERMPAno/edit`

I am passing in this value as the file ID: `1JRS8SLzaAD2U4cG-GbDMbVN25Dp6f_uUYyl6ERMPAno`.

When the code gets to this line: `File file = service.files().get(fileId).execute();`

I get this error:

```
An error occured: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 OK
{
"code" : 404,
"errors" : [ {
"domain" : "global",
"message" : "File not found: 1JRS8SLzaAD2U4cG-GbDMbVN25Dp6f_uUYyl6ERMPAno",
"reason" : "notFound"
 } ],
```

When I try to find the file in question using the tool at the bottom of [this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get), if I turn on Oauth 2.0, I get back a 200 response code and information about the file in question.

I've looked at many similar questions on here including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188752/get-childrens-files-from-a-an-id-folder-in-google-drive) question, but I can't see anything wrong in the way that I've set up my permissions:

- For my project, both the Drive API and Drive SDK are on under APIs and Auth.
- Under Credentials I see my client ID, Email addresss and Public Key fingerprints
- I've also verified on my domain's admin console that under security > API reference, enable API access is checked.
- Security > Advanced Settings > Manage API Client Access the following scope is added: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive with the service account's client ID.
- Security > Advanced > Manage Oauth Domain key:

  - The "enable this consumer key" checkbox is checked.
  - There is an oAuth consumer secret code.
  - There is no X.509 certificate.
  - The "two legged OAuth access control Allow access to all APIs" is unchecked.

Here is where I get the drive service:

```
        public static Drive getDriveService() throws GeneralSecurityException,
    IOException, URISyntaxException {

  HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
  JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
  GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
      .setTransport(httpTransport)
      .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
      .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
      //.setServiceAccountScopes(DriveScopes.DRIVE)
      .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPE)
      .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
          new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
      .build();
  Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
      .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();
  return service;
```

I have these variables defined as follows:

```
/** Email of the Service Account */
private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

/** Path to the Service Account's Private Key file */
private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = "/actualpathhere/HowToListing/war/resources/actualpd12filename.p12"; 
private static final List<String> SCOPE = Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly");
```

Here is where I am trying to get the file metadata:

```
private static List<File> retrieveAllFiles(Drive service) throws IOException {
        List<File> result = null;
        try {
            String fileId = "1JRS8SLzaAD2U4cG-GbDMbVN25Dp6f_uUYyl6ERMPAno";
            File file = service.files().get(fileId).execute();
            System.out.println("Title: " + file.getTitle());
            System.out.println("Description: " + file.getDescription());
            System.out.println("MIME type: " + file.getMimeType());

          } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occured: " + e);
          }


        return result;
      }
```

Can anyone give me any hints as to what might be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**

All the security was a red herring, it turns out.  The key thing missing was a valid user's email address.  First, functioning code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;


public class DriveCommandLine {


  private static String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL  = "11111-abc123@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
  private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_NAME = "a_file_name.p12";
  private static String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH; 

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
      //I did this stuff for the p12 file b/c I was having trouble doing this all from command line (first time)
      URL location = DriveCommandLine.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
      SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = location.getFile() + SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_NAME;

      Drive drive = DriveCommandLine.getDriveService("valid-user@example.com");
      DriveCommandLine.printFile(drive, "THE_ID_OF_THE_FILE");
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  //From https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation#instantiate_a_drive_service_object
  /**
   * Build and returns a Drive service object authorized with the service accounts
   * that act on behalf of the given user.
   *
   * @param userEmail The email of the user.
   * @return Drive service object that is ready to make requests.
   */
  public static Drive getDriveService(String userEmail) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
                                                                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                                                                .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
                                                                .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(new String[] {DriveScopes.DRIVE}))
                                                                .setServiceAccountUser(userEmail)
                                                                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
                                                                .build();
    Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null).setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();
    return service;
  }
  // From the code box at https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get
  /**
   * Print a file's metadata.
   *
   * @param service Drive API service instance.
   * @param fileId ID of the file to print metadata for.
   */
  private static void printFile(Drive service, String fileId) {

    try {
      File file = service.files().get(fileId).execute();

      System.out.println("Title: " + file.getTitle());
      System.out.println("Description: " + file.getDescription());
      System.out.println("MIME type: " + file.getMimeType());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("An error occured: " + e);
    }
  }
}
```

The missing line was `setServiceAccountUser(userEmail)` which is for a valid system user.

With a valid user, I got the file details.

With an invalid user, I got

```
An error occured: com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "Not a valid email."
}
```

And, with a user who did not have access or when the line was not set, I got

```
An error occured: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "File not found: THE_FILE_ID",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "File not found: THE_FILE_ID"
}
```

NOTE: Just be sure you follow each little step at [Perform Google Apps Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation#instantiate_a_drive_service_object) since that is where I ended up getting the solution and all the right keys (didn't need as many as I initially thought!)

Comment: Just edited so you can see how scope is defined.  I'm going to make sure I've set up the p12 file correctly...

Comment: Also I've tried the line of code you suggested `.setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE))` and I still get the same result - error 404.

Comment: That was one thing I noticed, but I checked your string and it matches the value of the constant.  Maybe the p12 thing is the case, then?

Comment: Well, I've been thinking about this and I do get back a drive service object.  So that says to me that the service account credentials are working properly.  The service account did not create the file I'm looking for (my personal user did) - does this have anything to do with my problem?

Comment: What I can't figure out is why it works here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get but not in my code.

Comment: Please see the edited post above.  You'd have been notified hours ago, but someone deleted my comment.